# How to match a regex exactly, without anything at the start or end?

Tags: regex

I've been looking through RegEx help for a bit now but I think I need a pro to help me through. I think this is possible with RegEx but can't figure out how.

This is the match I am looking for. If it doesn't match this exactly I want to know:

```
\w{2,4}\s\d{4}
```

I basically want to match for common school course names. The requirements are as follows:

1. First part is 2-4 letters
2. Second part is exactly 4 numbers
3. There must be a space between the two

If there is any other variation to this I want to stop my next bit of code from running. I can easily trim the left and right end for spaces, but I want to make sure there is nothing else in there.

My problem is that my current expression allows someone to put in COMD 1500-B. I still get a match and I understand why, but I want to make sure if someone enters in more than 4 numbers I can stop and throw an error. As well as having more than 4 letters. I thought the `{}` was supposed to make a max.

Comment: Are you using [start and end of string anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)? (ie: `^\w{2,4}\s\d{4}$`)?

Comment: just use ^ at the beginning and $ at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` denotes start of string, and `$` denotes end of string. As such, `^\w{2,4}\s\d{4}$` ensures the entire string matches the pattern, rather than just a subset of the string matching.

Comment: So that's what that meant... It's the obvious things I can never find posts about. Ty.

Comment: \s can be any of space, tab, carriage return and new line. If you just want a space replace \s with space.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud go with regex pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\s+\d{4}$
```

If just uppercase letters are allowed, then go with regex pattern

```
^[A-Z]{2,4}\s+\d{4}$
```

If just one space character is allowed, then replace `\s+` with `\s`. And if such space is only space-bar character (yes, we have more white-space characters), then replace `\s` with space-bar character .

```
^[A-Z]{2,4} \d{4}$
```